# Inhibiting a profile script while a transcription file is being used by the system

Tags: windows, powershell, transcription

I use a little script in a profile file in order to renew a transcript file when it becomes too large (past a given number of lines the process of renewal is triggered); what it does is initiate a copy of the transcript file, remove the transcript file and starts another transcript file with the same name. However, when starting supplementary instances of the ISE the script is run by again and when the limit on the number of lines on the transcript file has been reached that results in an error statement to the effect that the transcript file can't be removed as it is being used by a process (this process being the transcription on the main instance—there is no transcription for other instances than that initially opened in a session but nevertheless opening a new instance yields, at the top of the screen, a declaration saying that the transcript file has been started). How can I make the execution of the script conditional to the non utilisation of the transcript file by the system? The error message isn't such a problem as it is already a warning that the file is too big and as well as it can be ignored but it would be nicer not to have it on the top of the screen for each opening of a new instance.

Comment: This where PS Jobs come in play. You need to have isolated PS runspaces to deal this so that one cannot lock another.

Comment: @RanadipDutta How do you do that?

Comment: I will not write code for you. You can try looking into [THIS](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/parallel-processing-with-jobs-in-powershell/)

Comment: @RanadipDutta Thanks for the terms and the link.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is not a 100 % verified and I couldn't explain the principles involved but it works. More details about it can be found [here](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/ask_the_experts/f/learn_powershell-12/8766/how-to-check-whether-a-file-is-open?ReplySortBy=CreatedDate&ReplySortOrder=Ascending), the source of the switch.
It is only necessary to choose for the variable "$filename" the path of your transcript file and to insert your  script for file content storage and renewal in the second field of the if instruction.

```
$fileName = <path of transcript file>
$file = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileInfo -ArgumentList $fileName
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
[System.IO.FileStream] $fs = $file.OpenWrite(); 
if (!$?) {} else {$fs.Dispose();<script for file content storage and renewal>  
                 }
```